# Is there any URL info / meta data webservice API?

Tags: python, web-services, api, google-app-engine, url

Is there any known URL info API which will provide data like title, description, content-type, image etc? I researched a bit but have not come across any such API. Eventually, I have ventured out creating something like from scratch.

The consumption of such API can be for various web apps which need to display URL information. A typical real world example is Facebook using something similar when you share / attach a link in a status update.

Suggestions welcomed as it will save me the effort of maintaining such a webservice myself.

**Edit:**

Found two good sources which can be helpful

1. [Protonet - The Art Of Turning URLs Into A User Readable Preview](http://blog.protonet.info/post/1005627617/art-of-turning-urls-into-user-readable-previews)
2. Using [YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/) to do a quick fetch
3. [Iframely](http://iframely.com/gateway/API) web service

**Edit:**

After much research and to address my specific use-case, I created my own API that is hosted on Google App Engine for this. Someone looking for this, may get in touch.

Comment: What did you end up doing? I need such a service myself. I understand the concepts, but it seems like a lot of work.

Comment: @nute I landed up creating a service which is running on Google App Engine. Here's the [sample output](http://xurlapi.appspot.com/api/info?url=http://edition.cnn.com/2012/09/21/business/menon-india-supermarkets/index.html&onerror=1&unicode=1&apikey=YWtzaGF5LnJhamVAZ21haWwuY29t). But its not an open API. Please get in touch with me if you want to use / implement it.

Comment: I'd love to get in touch with you, but it seems there is no such feature. Send me an email at nathan.hazout {at} sticknshare {dot} com

Answer (score 0):

There's no such API to the best of my knowledge, simply because accessing such an API wouldn't be much simpler than just fetching the page itself.

Comment: An API would have 2 main advantages over local fetching and parsing - firstly caching (beneficial for popular URLs) and secondly, a lean response (just the stuff you need - not the whole page)

Comment: @AkshayRaje True, but you have to decide if that outweighs the issues of depending on an extra service (and its uptime and reliability). And a user of the service probably doesn't care much if there's a caching layer between them and the site they're querying - only the owner of the target site is likely to care about that. ;)

Comment: I agree. I guess a lean response is the only real advantage. I think I will go ahead and make it - anyways am using free tier of Google App Engine and hence have nothing much to loose beyond coding effort and I would anyways need it for a web app that am working on.

Answer (score 0):

I like the idea and I think you should try to implement it and "sell" it to other web developers.  Of course there will be a trust issue -- will they trust you not to lie?

Comment: Yes, I will implement it anyways as I need to consume it for a web app that am working on. Am using Google App Engine so that it is scalable and free (at least till a certain level of usage). Didn't really understand the trust issue here. Why wont someone trust such a simple webservice? Frankly there is no motive to 'lie' in this case.